# Extending module functionality in python

Tags: python, oop, module, composition

I have a series of modules, each of which contains a behavior which I want to mix into a class via composition. Since each of these modules has some common & redundant code, I attempted to extract out a base module which I could then import into each module, filling in the custom code while cutting out the boilerplate. A simplified version of my code is below:

main.py:

```
import concrete as steak_sauce

class Customer():

    def __init__(self):
        self.allergies = ["onions"]
        self.dish = []

    def register_ingredient (steak_sauce):
        self.dish.append(ingredient)


customer = Customer()


customer.eat_if_not_allergic(steak_sauce)
```

base.py:

```
# Base module

menu_item_name = "default"
menu_item_ingredients = []

def is_allergic(customer):
    if menu_item_name in customer.allergies:
        return True
    else:
        add_to_dish(menu_item_name)

def eat_if_not_allergic(customer):
    if not is_allergic(customer):
        eat_it(ingredient)
```

concrete.py:

```
from base import *

menu_item_name = "steak sauce"
menu_item_ingredients = ["MSG", "Blood"]

def eat_it(customer):
    print "custom logic acting on customer goes here"
```

When I run main.py, I get an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 14, in <module>
    customer.add_if_not_allergic(steak_sauce)
  File "main.py", line 10, in add_if_not_allergic
    if not ingredient.is_allergic(customer):
  File "/home/chazu/tests/base.py", line 10, in is_allergic
    add_to_dish(menu_item_name)
NameError: global name 'eat_it' is not defined
```

My question is this: Is there a way to extend the functionality of a module, or inversely to extract common functionality out of multiple modules into a base module, without lots of extra lines of code? What is the pythonic way?

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: is there a reason not to make is_allergic() a method of Customer? add_to_dish() looks like it should be a Customer method too.

Comment: In my use case, each ingredient will need to implement custom behavior in the add_to_dish() method...And I want to be able to add that functionality into Customer without having to inherit every ingredient...My example doesn't illustrate that very well, actually. I need to edit it when I'm able.

Comment: Is there a reason to break all the code up?  Your problem in the exception is that you haven't imported "add_to_dish" into base.py.

Comment: If eat_if_not_allergic is identical for every ingredient, I thought I'd avoid extra code in each ingredient. I do see no reason why is_allergic can't go into Customer though...Is hoped that I could import eat_if_not_allergic into concrete and that it could call concrete's eat_it, allowing me to need only to specify the custom code in each ingredient.

Comment: If Customer is going to eat_it() and the customer holds the allergies it makes sense that these are performed by the customer as methods.  If you have special logic for ingredients you probably should have an Ingredient object.

Comment: I think I see how this can be rearranged, rolling the 'test allergy' logic into Customer and executing custom logic by passing the customer to the ingredient. I shall reimplement when the sun reaches my side of the earth. Thank you =)